# How to remove Protections Dashboard from Firefox menu

Tags: firefox

How can I remove the new Protections Dashboard entry from the Firefox menu?

Might as well remove the sign in entry and the separators, too!

Answer (score 0):

- Open *about:config* page.
- Flip *toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets* to true.
- Open *about:support* page.
- Click *Open Folder* in the *Profile Folder* row.
- Open (or create then open) *chrome* folder.
- Open (or create then open) *userChrome.css* file.
- Add the following and save:

  ```
  #appMenu-fxa-status,
  #appMenu-protection-report-button,
  #appMenu-mainView toolbarseparator:nth-of-type(-n+2) {
      display: none;
  }
  ```
- Restart Firefox.

fxa status is the sign in; protection report is the protections dashboard; -n+2 is to hide the first 2 separators